# How to read numbers as one in a ArrayList of Characters not using Stack

Tags: java, arraylist

> I'm creating an ArrayList of Characters to read every single one of my input. If my inputs are 0-9 my ctr will +1 and when my inputs are operators my ctr will -1 but how can i read this number (for example 12) as one statement only? What's the best option can i get?
>
> Heres my Code:

```
  class Validation2
{
 static Scanner input=new Scanner(System.in);
 static String confirmation = null;
public static void main(String args[])
{
   
    int ctr=0;
    ArrayList<Character> list=new ArrayList<Character>();
    String notation;
   
     
    do
    {
        
        System.out.println("Enter Postfix Notation: ");
        notation =input.nextLine();
    
    if(notation.matches("[A-Za-z]") || notation.matches("[\\p{Punct}&&[^_]]+"))
    {
        System.out.println("Invalid Input sorry.");
    }
    else if(notation.charAt(0) <= 0 || notation.charAt(1) >= 9)
    {
     for(int x = 0; x < notation.length(); x++)
     {
        list.add(notation.charAt(x));
        
        if(list.get(x).equals('/') || list.get(x).equals('*')||list.get(x).equals('-')|| list.get(x).equals('+'))
        {
                 ctr--;
                 System.out.println(list.get(x));
        }
         else if(list.get(x) <= 0 || list.get(x) >= 9)
                 ctr++;
        
         }
     }
    else if(notation.charAt(0) == '/' || notation.charAt(0) == '*' || notation.charAt(0) == '-' || notation.charAt(0) == '+' ||
            notation.charAt(1) == '/' || notation.charAt(1) == '*' || notation.charAt(1) == '-' || notation.charAt(1) == '+')
            System.out.println("The first two numbers should be operands");
    
    if(ctr == 1)
    {
        System.out.println("The post fix is valid");
        
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("The post fix is invalid");
    }
    
    System.out.println(ctr);
    ctr = 0;
    list.clear();
    System.out.println("Do you want to Continue? Y/N");
    confirmation = input.nextLine().toUpperCase();
    
    
   
     }while(confirmation.equals("Y"));
    
    
}
```

Comment: Well, you say you have a list of characters, and `12` are two characters, a `1` and a `2`. How did you came by the character array? Was it originally a String and you've converted it to a char-array and you want digit to stay combined as a single number? Could you post some more code from before this for-loop, like where you make the list and an example of your input.

Comment: Use a char array and switch. Also chars are not a number. your if statement is flawed. ( 0 - 9 are the only valid digits for charAt).

Comment: Why not use subString method in the String class and then toInt it to compare it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use an Array List for Postfix notation. Use a simple stack and remove numbers accordingly to the operator. A stack can be implemented with a simple Deque (eg. LinkedList).

This is a sample implementation:

```
package tk.manf.util.collection;

import java.util.Deque;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;

/**
 * LiFo implementation using a LinkedList
 * @author Björn 'manf' Heinrichs
 */
public class Stack<V> implements Iterable<V> {
    private final Deque<V> data;

    public Stack() {
        this.data = new LinkedList<>();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves and removes the last element of this stack. This method 
     * throws an exception if this stack is empty.
     *
     * @return the tail of this deque
     * @throws java.util.NoSuchElementException if this stack is empty
     */
    public V remove() {
        return data.removeLast();
    }

    /**
     * Retrieves, but does not remove, the last inserted element
     * or returns {@code null} if this stack is empty.
     *
     * @return the last inserted element or {@code null} if this stack is empty
     */
    public V top() {
        return data.peekLast();
    }

    public int size() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public void add(V t) {
        data.add(t);
    }

    public void clear() {
        data.clear();
    }

    @Override
    public Iterator<V> iterator() {
        return data.iterator();
    }
}
```

([SRC](https://github.com/MCSeu/ACalc/blob/master/src/main/java/tk/manf/util/collection/Stack.java))

Answer (score 0):

A `Character(objects) ArrayList` is not ideal for holding single characters. Instead use a `CharSequence ArrayList`, and manipulate the `CharSequence` objects the same way you'd manipulate `Strings`.